# Have the USA ever suspended visa services in any NATO state before Turkey?

Tags: united-states, turkey, nato

The United States suspended visa services in Turkey a few days ago ([CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/10/08/world/us-turkey-halt-visa-service/index.html)). I wonder if that has happened in any other NATO state before. A web search only returned the states that are currently restricted from visa issuance ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_United_States#Visa_issuance_restricted)).

> Visa issuance restricted:
>
> - Cambodia
> - Eritrea
> - Guinea
> - Sierra Leone
> - Cuba
> - Turkey

Answer (score 1):

The US has periodically stopped issuing Visas when closing consulates, but nothing wholesale to date in a Nato country insofar as I'm aware. [Example](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:wiEcAjL9x5EJ:https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/countries-with-limited-or-no-u-s--visa-services.html) taken from Google Cache:

[image]